# Ordering of sed command breaks for unknown reason

Tags: linux, bash, sed

#### Input

File.txt

```
Start
1
2
3
4
Start
5
6
7
8
```

---

#### Problem

I was messing around with sed to work out different ways to get data from between the `Start`s.

One script i made was

```
sed ':2;h;$!N;$b1;/\n.*Start[^\n]*$/{:1;$!x;/5/p;x;s/.*\n//};$!b2;d'
```

Explanation of script

```
:2 #A label for the break point

;h #Hold all the lines currently in the pattern buffer, i use this before getting the next line so that it doesn't have the next start.

 ;$!N # Gets the next line for every line except the last
  
 ;$b1 # Breaks to label 1 on the last line. This is to bypass having to see start to enter the block


 ;/\n.*Start[^\n]*$/ # If start is on the last line of pattern buffer then execute the next block

  { #Start of block

  :1 #Label to jump to if end of file

  ;$!x # If not the last line switch in the hold buffer we got which doesn't include the next `Start`.

  ;/5/p # Print if this Start section contains `5`

  ;x #Switch back hold buffer and pattern to get `Start` back

  ;s/.*\n// #Delete everything up to last line of pattern buffer(leaving just `Start`.

  } # End block

  ;$!b2 # If not end of file go back to label at the start

  ;d #Deletes anything left in pattern buffer when we reach the end of the file
```

Outputs

```
Start
5
6
7
8
```

Which is correct

But changing the order of `$!N;$b1;` to `$b1;$!N` makes the script output nothing.

```
sed ':2;h;$b1;$!N;/\n.*Start[^\n]*$/{:1;$!x;/5/p;x;s/.*\n//};$!b2;d'
```

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious, or don't really understand the meaning of `$` but it seems to me as though this should make no difference as one command only executes on the last line(`$`) and the other on all other lines, so the ordering shouldn't matter should it?

Any explanations are welcome and if any more info is needed let me know.

Also I DO NOT want a better way of doing this, I just want an explanation of why it is happening.

---

#### More Info

- GNU sed version 4.1.5

Comment: You could probably get more answers if you explained your logic. Even those of us who grok `sed` have a problem with its write-only syntax; and explaining what you want is always a good idea anyway.

Comment: @triplee Oki doke, I'll add one now :)

Comment: @triplee Explanation added. Also whilst you are here, do you know of any tool to get sed to output what it's doing, as it would make debugging it significantly easier ?

Comment: At a guess, `$!N;$b1` at the line before last first appends, then branches (as it is now the final line), wheras `$b1;$!N` doesn't branch, appends, doesn't enter the block. following is `$!b2` which isn't taken, followed by `d` deleting the pattern. (and ending the script, as there is no more input)

Comment: @Hasturkun Yep, that's it, I knew it would be something obvious! IF you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it, otherwise I'll delete the question. Thankyou for your help :)

Comment: It wasn't really that obvious, I used [sedsed](http://aurelio.net/projects/sedsed/) on a smaller snippet to check, but it still left me a bit confused about the lastness of the line following `N` in this case. I won't post an answer since I'm not entirely convinced I understood this correctly.

Comment: Lol, who's downvoted this question from months ago haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$!N;$b1` at the line before last first appends, then branches (as it is now the final line), wheras `$b1;$!N` doesn't branch, appends, doesn't enter the block. following is `$!b2` which isn't taken, followed by `d` deleting the pattern. (and ending the script, as there is no more input) – Hasturkun